# How to capture the name using Regex in the following html

Tags: regex

What would be the most reliable way of capturing the name from the following html:

[Live Regex101 working example](https://regex101.com/r/wR2iK8/1)

I managed to get the name using:

```
View itineraryYour Guest.+?(?=>).+?(\s+[^\s].+?(?=<))
```

However this does not work in the code, just in the Regex example. anyone have any good ways of capturing such string?

EDIT:

This is what i was looking for.

```
View itineraryYour Guest\s*<[^>]*>\s*([^\s<>]+(?:\s*[^\s<>])*)
```

Comment: Do you mean to just match a name after a tag-like entity? See [this demo](http://goo.gl/ks30Un), is it what you need?

Comment: @stribizhev I actually just wanted the Regex expression for this, the demo rreturn me null

Comment: It returns `Aditi Reddy`. And the regex is `$re = '/View itineraryYour Guest\s*<[^>]*>\s*([^\s<>]+(?:\s*[^\s<>])*)/'`. Why did you remove PHP tag? I will delete `nsregularexpression` since most probably you are not coding it for iOS.

Comment: @stribizhev I was only looking for the expression. I have updated the answer

Comment: FWIW, that is not HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
View itineraryYour Guest\s*<[^>]*>\s*([^\s<>]+(?:\s*[^\s<>])*)
```

The `\s*` matches any optional whitespace symbols, `<[^>]*>` matches `<...>`-like substrings, and `[^\s<>]` matches any character other than `<`, `>` or whitespace.

The result is in Group 1.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vC7bJ0/1)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, great help!